# How to Redirect specific paths to different folder using nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx

Basically i have 3 different folders inside a main folder(example).

1 simple html page, 1 angular website, and 1 wordpress website.
lets name them

1. static.html
2. angular_website
3. wordpress_website

So the main domain name
[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) should open code from the static_html page.

The sub domain
[www.example.com/site1](http://www.example.com/site1) should direct to / open the angular_website folder

and the sub domain
[www.example.com/site2](http://www.example.com/site2) should direct to the wordpress_website folder.

following is my code.

```
server {
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 server_name example.com www.example.com;
 root /var/www/example/;

 location =/ {
    alias /var/www/example/
 }

 location =/site1 {
    rewrite ^/$ http://www.example.com/site1/redirectothis/ permanent;
 }

 location /site1 {
        alias /var/www/example/angular_website/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        expires $expires;
 }

 location /site2 {
    alias /var/www/example/wordpress_website/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires $expires;
 }
}
```

Please Help as i am not able to load the angular website from the path also i am doing a small redirection so that the right page is opnened for my angular website.